# Semi transparent full screen layer on top of the map tiles

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, core-location

Is there any way to add black semi transparent full screen layer on top of the map tiles ? 
like Nike GPS app. ([Example screen is here](http://fatihyasar.com/Nike.GPS.screen.jpg))

Comment: how about you add a UIView with black background and alfa = 0.5 on index 0

Answer (score 0):

A UIMapView is just a view. You can do anything above it in the view hierarchy. You should look at the drawing and overlay functions within the MapKit docs for annotating or doing overlays based on the coordinate space.

Also, you might find it easier to take on device screenshots by holding the power button and pressing the home button. You don't need to take a camera photo.